# in Python, I get a wrong total, i only get the total of the positive numbers that are located before the negative ones

Tags: python, negative-integer

i wrote this code in python:

```
list=[3,5,7,6,-9,5,4]
i=0
total=0
while i<len(list) and list[i] > 0:
     total+=list[i]
     i+=1
print(total)
```

and instead of getting the total of all positive numbers i only get the total of numbers that are located before the negative one, i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, this is just my fourth code in python i'd like some help^^

Comment: Here you should not be using a `while` loop. Think about it: a while loop will continue executing *while numbers remain positive* and stop as soon as it encounters the first negative number. Use `for` loop instead or change conditional expressions in your while loop.

Comment: @pavel it is not an issue that ```while``` loop is being used or ```for``` loop. The code will work well in both the cases, considered that appropriate conditions are put.

Comment: @SwatiSrivastava While a `while` will work, it is the wrong tool to use in this case.  Iteration over containers is more simple with a `for` loop.  No need for initializing or incrementing an index, and if you need the index, use `for i,item in enumerate(lst)`.  Even more simple for this case is a list comprehension.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I agree with ```for``` works better in iterating conditions, but using ```while``` may not be wrong, just inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand the working of while loop. It works as long as `i < len(list` and `list[i] > 0`. When it reaches the value `-9`, the while loop's second condition gets false and it terminates. Hence no sum is calculated after first negative integer is encountered.

To solve this, do

```
lis = [3, 5, 7, 6, -9, 5, 4]
sum = 0
for i in lis:
    if i > 0:
        sum += i
```

For your while loop code, use

```
lis = [3, 5, 7, 6, -9, 5, 4]
i = 0
sum = 0
while i < len(lis):
    if lis[i] > 0:
        sum += lis[i]
    i = i + 1
```

Also, although you can use a variable name as `list`, it is advised not to do so in Python as `list` is also a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have the condition that the loop ends if you encounter a negative number. You can first remove that condition from the loop.

```
while i<len(list):
```

Next, you only want to add non-negative numbers so, use a conditional statement in the loop with the condition that you want.

```
if list[i] > 0:
```

Comment: thank you! i've tried this solution but now i only get in the output the first number which is 3

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a `while` loop in this case.  Iteration over items in a container is easier in Python with a `for` loop.  Plus the logic is wrong and exits the `while` loop early when it fails the `and list[i] > 0` condition.

```
lst = [3,5,7,6,-9,5,4]
total = 0
for item in lst:
    if item > 0:
        total += item
print(total)
```

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name.  That replaces the built-in `list` type and is called "shadowing".

You can also use a list comprehension and simplify the code even more:

```
lst = [3,5,7,6,-9,5,4]
total = sum([item for item in lst if item > 0])
print(total)
```